# Regression test the Jenkins Shared Libraries

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am actually looking to regression test our jenkins shared libraries and could not find any framework or solution so far. I tried Jenkins pipeline unit-writing the unit test cases and mocking the jenkins global variables but discovered that it did not work in our case as we have a lot of jenkins shared libraries wrriten in groovy/boto3/aws cloudformation templates. need some info if there is any solution available or if anyone has done this before so that i can get some help

Answer (score 0):

I followed a much basic approach, for (IMHO) real unit tests: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jenkins-global-shared-pipeline-libraries-real-unit-delgado-garrido/

Groovy code can be tested as plain Groovy (even CPS trasnformation cause it not to be real Groovy)